# How can I have material-ui autocomplete base on first input field that users selected or inputted

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, material-ui

I have two input field, where one is a list of country and another list of school.

How can I have autocomplete be based on country selected.

For example, user clicks on Dublin, only list of school in Dublin should be listed in autocomplete

[County](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha4Ni.png)
[School](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI5EV.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYF7Y.png)
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG0jB.png)

Comment: Please copy your code into the question into *Code Sample* blocks, it makes your question more readable. Just mark the code while editing and click on the `Code Sample` icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Autocomplete component you should filter the getSchool list by the selectedCountry. Imagine that on the school list you have the country of it as `country` you should do the following

```
<Autocomplete
  options={getschool.filter(x => x.country === selectedCountry}
  ...
  ...
/>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I am new to react js and material ui. I was about to create an entire function to filter. Didn't know I could do these with autocomplete :)

Comment: Yw! If it was working feel free to vote up my answer :)